# Can I create a union type of all exported types in a namespace?

Tags: typescript, swagger

I use [dts-gen](https://github.com/microsoft/dts-gen) to generate typescript definition files from swagger.

It produces a `.d.ts` file with contents like -

```
namespace Responses {
    export type $200 = Definitions.InternalCostreportingApiFlowsResponse;
    export type $401 = Definitions.ErrorResponseMessage;
    export type $403 = Definitions.ErrorResponseMessage;
    export type $404 = Definitions.ErrorResponseMessage;
    export type $500 = Definitions.ErrorResponseMessage;
}
```

I use these definitions in my UI code to ensure that the types for the API's which are defined in swagger match the types that the UI code uses.

For this example, to capture all the response types, I write code like

```
return this.get<
        | Paths.V1CostreportingFlows.Get.Responses.$200
        | Paths.V1CostreportingFlows.Get.Responses.$401
        | Paths.V1CostreportingFlows.Get.Responses.$403
        | Paths.V1CostreportingFlows.Get.Responses.$404
        | Paths.V1CostreportingFlows.Get.Responses.$500
    >(
        '/v1/costreporting/flows?date=' +
            format(endDate, 'yyyy-MM-dd') +
            '&duration_days=' +
            differenceInDays(endDate, startDate)
    );
```

which is a lot of typing, which I would like to avoid. I can simplify that code to something like

```
return this.get<
        Paths.V1CostreportingFlows.Get.Responses.$200 | Definitions.ErrorResponseMessage
    >(
        '/v1/costreporting/flows?date=' +
            format(endDate, 'yyyy-MM-dd') +
            '&duration_days=' +
            differenceInDays(endDate, startDate)
    );
```

but I am unhappy with using `Definitions.ErrorResponseMessage` as it may be a bit brittle if the types change for one of the error codes.

I would like to know if there is a way to create a union type out of all the exported types in the `Responses` namespace.  Something like `<UnionOfNamespace<Paths.V1CostreportingFlows.Get.Responses>>`?